# error ORA-01031, this is shown when i try to create a tablespace. what can i do?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I tried to create a tablespace for an assignment I have, where it must contain
indexes and data from a user and it shows me this error.

I tried online tutorials, asking teachers and even SQL command line, nothing worked.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE john DATAFILE 'JOHN.DBF' SIZE 50m;
```

I expect to create a tablespace, but it shows the error.

Comment: you are not allowed to create tablespace, contact your dba

Answer (score 1):

Error you got means **insufficient privileges**.

Are you a DBA? Apparently not. Tablespaces are created by privileged users (such as SYS or SYSTEM or - even better - the one you created to do administrative tasks), not by *anyone* (such as developers).

Here's an example: first, trying to do that connected as Scott (poor user that owns EMP and DEPT tables and is used for testing purposes):

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE john DATAFILE 'JOHN.DBF' size 50m;
CREATE TABLESPACE john DATAFILE 'JOHN.DBF' size 50m
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Of course Scott can't do that. But, System can:

```
SQL> connect system/pwd
Connected.
SQL> CREATE TABLESPACE john DATAFILE 'JOHN.DBF' size 50m;

Tablespace created.
```

Therefore:

- if you are a DBA, you should be able to do that if connected as a privileged user
- if you are not, talk to the DBA. They might, or might not do what you want